# Mysql Regexp: match a list of words in a paragraph with regex

Tags: mysql, regex

i have a paragraph like this:

> An automobile, autocar, motor car or car is a wheeled motor vehicle used for transporting passengers, which also carries its own engine or motor. Most definitions of the term specify that automobiles are designed to run primarily on roads, to have seating for one to eight people, to typically have four wheels, and to be constructed principally for the transport of people rather than goods.

i have a regexp code for match my words list with this paragpraph but it is not working:

```
[[:<:]]((automobile|motor|roads|bycicle)[[:blank:]]*){2,}[[:>:]]
```

how can i edit this regexp code to match with this pagagrapgh ?

Comment: what do you want to do with the paragraph?

Comment: i am writing a search query with this, "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE summary RLIKE $regex"

Comment: In the paragraphs you have, there is a comma after each word, maybe you should try `(automobile|motor|roads|bycicle),[[:blank:]]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You claim that you want to match words within the paragraph. But your regular expression only matches sequences of **at least two** words from the list (due to the `{2,}`. Those words may be separated by whitespace, but could also be written dirrectly one after the other with no space in between. If you only want to match single words, why not simply use

```
[[:<:]](automobile|motor|roads|bycicle)[[:>:]]
```

Comment: because i want to match more than one words :)

Comment: @mohammad: Well, the example paragraph you gave us does not contain any two *consecutive* words from your list, so there won't be a match in there. I guess you should edit your question to explain exactly what you *want* to match, so people can figure out in what way your regular expression is wrong. So far, the question reads “this does not what I want it to do”, with little info on what you *would* want it to do.